# How can I specify an interaction term in a non linear regression using the SSasymp function in R?

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

How can I specify an interaction term -in `lm` as `x:z`- in a non linear regression using the SSasymp function? And random effects -in `lm` as `(1|z)`-?

This is my model with one predictor only:

```
library(nlme)
nlme(y ~ SSasymp(x, Asym, R0, lrc),
        data = na.omit(df),
        fixed = Asym + R0 + lrc ~ 1,
        random = Asym ~ 1|z,
        start = c(Asym = 1.1, R0 = 2.0, lrc = 4.9))
```

I understand that in the model above I have x as a fixed effect, and random intercept for z.

However, how do I specify an interaction between x and z? That is, the equivalent of what in `lm` we would do by `x*z` or by `x + z + x:z`?

Comment: We need some more details, please. `nlme` is what you want to handle random effects. Nonlinear models have another layer of structure, though: if the **top-level** parameters are the parameters in the nonlinear model (`Asym`, `R0`, `lrc` in your case) then we add structure to the model by adding fixed-effect or random-effect *linear* sub-models for one or more of the parameters, e.g. in `nlme` we could specify `fixed = Asym ~ x, random = Asym ~ 1|g` to specify that the asymptote followed a linear model with fixed effect `x` and intercept variation across levels of `g`

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bolker, very useful. I have downloaded the nlme library and I have edited the question with more info. I am now able to run random intercepts for z. But still wondering how I can add an interaction term to the regression.

Comment: I assume `z` is a factor since you're using it as the grouping variable in a random effect term -- please confirm?

Comment: `y` is a continuous dependent variable, `x` is a continuous independent predictor, `z` is another continuous independent predictor. But i also have other independent predictors (let's say `g` that are discrete and that can be seen as a factor with different levels. I intend to create different models, and then compare AIC. So it would be nice to know how to add all this variables as main effects, interactions and random effects.

Comment: do you need any other info @Ben Bolker?

Answer (score 1):

(Not necessarily an answer but seems too long for a comment.)

I'm still not sure this makes sense to me. Let's consider a simplified version of the question. Suppose you wanted to fit an exponential decay model (`y ~ a*exp(-b*x)`, but you wanted to include "an interaction between `x` and `z`".  This would most naturally be formulated as "a change in the (exponential) slope with respect to `x` as `z` changes"; you could write this out as

```r
nls(y ~ a*exp(-b*x),
    params = list(a ~ 1, b ~ z),
    ...)
```

(or the equivalent for `nlme`, which would involve `fixed = list(a ~ 1, b ~ z)`, as well as a `random=` component).  Expanding this specification out, this would be equivalent to replacing `b` by `beta0 + beta1*z`, or:

```r
y ~ a*exp(-(beta0 + beta1*z)*x)
  ~ a*exp(-beta0*x + beta1*z*x)
```

In other words, interactions are usually expressed in terms of the effects of one covariate *on the effects of another covariate*, or *variation in effective parameter values with respect to a covariate*. If you want to include "an interaction between x and z" in your model, I think you need to be more specific: **which** of the parameters governing the pattern of `y` with respect to `x` varies with `z`? Most generally, you could write `fixed = Asym + R0 + lrc ~ z`, which would correspond to a model (ignoring the random effects)

```
y ~ (Asym1+Asym2*z)+((R01+R02*z)-(Asym1+Asym2*z))*exp(-exp(lrc1+lrc2*z)*input)
```

In other words, each of the parameters has been replaced by a linear function of `z` with corresponding linear parameters (`foo1` (intercept), `foo2` (slope)).

You could also write this out in the full form as given here, but estimation would probably be less efficient (and the formula would be harder to read).

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bolker. However, I don't fully understand how i could implement this. What are a and b in your first model? Could you clarify how I can implement these interactions and random effects between x and z by making it explicit in a model that follows the structure of the example I shared in the question?